# How to get a div overlapping another

Tags: html, css

```
<header>
<div>
  <h1>Midorikawa's Site</h1>
  <hr />
  <!--<p>Work in progress</p>-->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Quote</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Photographs</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="wallpaper"></div><!-- THIS div has to go underneath the other div -->
</header>
```

the "wallpaper" div has to go underneath the other div the "wallpaper" div is javascript activated and switches wallpaper with an fade but i have no idea how to get it underneath the other div please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` on the first div:

Refer code:

```
<header>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Midorikawa's Site</h1>
  <hr />
  <!--<p>Work in progress</p>-->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Quote</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Photographs</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="wallpaper"></div><!-- THIS div has to go underneath the other div -->
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.body {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The div wont be centered when i change the position

Comment: You didn't mention you want it to be cetered in your original question. Check edited code to make it appear in the center.

Comment: One more question it's now centered left and right how do i also get it vertical

Answer (score 0):

Use css property z-index on your divs. The one which you need on top should have higher z-index than the one that should be underneath it (I coloured the divs for visual).

```
<div style="position:absolute">
<h1>Midorikawa's Site</h1>
<hr />
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Quote</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Photographs</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="wallpaper" style="width:50px;height:100px;background-color:red;z- index:-5"></div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't go underneath

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` on both children of `<header>`.
Use positive `z-index` on the div you want on top.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sukritchhabra/89f1est4/